# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filename'. Flask-Restplus doesn't seem to recognize uploaded file as Filestorage object

Tags: file-upload, flask, flask-restful, werkzeug, flask-restplus

I am trying to upload 2 files(an audio and image file) along with some data.  I am very new to using Flask, but after reviewing other people with Filestorage issues, I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
class FiguresResource(Resource):
    parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        'thing',
        type=str)
    parser.add_argument(
        'image_file',
        type=werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage,
        location=UPLOAD_FOLDER)
    parser.add_argument(
        'audio_file',
        type=werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage,
        location=UPLOAD_FOLDER)

    def post(self):
        db = connect(MONGODB_DB, host=MONGODB_HOST, port=MONGODB_PORT)
        data = self.parser.parse_args()
        image = data['image_file']
        audio = data['audio_file']
        fig = Figure(
            data['thing'],
            image.filename,
            get_file_size(image),
            audio.filename,
            get_file_size(audio)
        )
        image.save(image.filename)
        audio.save(audio.filename)
        fig.save()
        db.close()
```

When I try to send the data I get an 'Internal Server Error' 500 from my requesting client.  The flask-rest server will throw---

> File "/home/joe/Projects/PyKapi-venv/kapi/resources/figure_resource.py", line 53, in post
>       image.filename,
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filename'
>   127.0.0.1 - - [20/May/2018 17:12:25] "POST /figures HTTP/1.1" 500 -

I thought the issue was in my Http request, but not so sure now.  I was initially sending my request with Postman, but have recently switched to using curl.  This is my curl command---

```
curl -F thing=Fruits -F image_file=@/home/joe/Projects/Pics/Fruits.jpg -F audio_file=@/home/joe/Projects/Audio/Fruits http://127.0.0.1:5000/figures
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UPDATE] I was using the locations argument in the requestparser() wrong. 
 The location arguement wants the content-type of the request.  So I changed it as follows~

```
class FiguresResource(Resource):
    parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        'thing',
        type=str,
        location='form')
    parser.add_argument(
        'image_file',
        type=FileStorage,
        location='files')
    parser.add_argument(
        'audio_file',
        type=FileStorage,
        location='files')

    def post(self):
        data = self.parser.parse_args()
        image = data['image_file']
        audio = data['audio_file']
        image_path = join(IMAGE_FOLDER, image.filename)
        audio_path = join(AUDIO_FOLDER, audio.filename)

        db = connect(MONGODB_DB, host=MONGODB_HOST, port=MONGODB_PORT)
        if Figure.objects(visual_aid_path=image_path):
            db.close()
            return {"message": "Visual Aid file with that name already exists"}
        if Figure.objects(audio_aid_path=audio_path):
            db.close()
            return {"message": "Audio file with that name already exists"}
        fig = Figure(
            data['thing'],
            image_path,
            audio_path
        )
        image.save(image_path)
        audio.save(audio_path)
        image.close()
        audio.close()
        fig.save()
        db.close()
```

`